# Is there anyway to access to the values groupby in python

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on a project and I was able to groupby 7D and now I want to access the elements groupedby
Here is the code:

```
    group = df.set_index('date').groupby('user').resample('7D', convention='start', label='left')
group_result = pd.DataFrame({'Weekly_in_averge_amount': group.mean()['value'], 'Weekly_in_max_amount': group.max()['value']'Weekly_in_min_amount': group.min()['value'], 'Weekly_in_totalamount': group.sum()['value'], 'Weekly_in_degree': group.sum()['inputs'], 'monthdays': group.count()['month']})`
groupUser = group_result.groupby('user').first()
```

I got this output

```
29                   1.512015  ...                1.049153
30                  34.896646  ...               26.350528
37                   0.055000  ...                0.002245
38                   0.835067  ...                0.102253
39                  38.044883  ...                9.317114
40                   1.476168  ...                0.090378
41                   1.000000  ...                0.061224
42                   8.976852  ...                0.183201
43                   0.012000  ...                0.000490
44                   2.377267  ...                0.048516
45                   1.365204  ...              284.463992
```

For example the user 29 has the transaction of one week, Is it possible to display the grouped values in user 29

```
    user   date                 Weekly_in_averge_amount   count
    29   2011-05-25                 1.512015  ...         34
    29   2011-06-01                 1.123298  ...         23
```

As we can see, user 29 has grouped all rows by one week. How can I get the rows grouped by one week.

Note that there are 34 rows grouped by the first group

sorry if my explanation is not clear
Thank you for any help

Regards,

Khaled

Comment: Are you trying to extract each row? Or items in that row? Please be specific.

Comment: I am trying to extract items in that row

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with dictionary of columns names and aggregate functions, then convert `MultiIndex` to columns, flatten and last `rename`:

```
np.random.seed(123)

rng = pd.date_range('2017-04-03', periods=10)
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': rng, 
                   'value': range(10), 
                   'inputs': range(3,13), 
                   'month': np.random.randint(1,7, size=10), 
                   'user':['a'] * 3 + ['b'] *3 + ['c'] *4})  
print (df)
        date  value  inputs  month user
0 2017-04-03      0       3      6    a
1 2017-04-04      1       4      3    a
2 2017-04-05      2       5      5    a
3 2017-04-06      3       6      3    b
4 2017-04-07      4       7      2    b
5 2017-04-08      5       8      4    b
6 2017-04-09      6       9      3    c
7 2017-04-10      7      10      4    c
8 2017-04-11      8      11      2    c
9 2017-04-12      9      12      2    c
```

---

```
df1  = (df.set_index('date')
          .groupby('user')
          .resample('7D', convention='start', label='left')
          .agg({'value': ['mean','max','min','sum'],
                'inputs':'sum',
                'month':'count'}))
df1.columns = df1.columns.map('_'.join)

d = {'value_max':'Weekly_in_max_amount',
     'value_min':'Weekly_in_min_amount',
     'value_sum':'Weekly_in_totalamount',
     'inputs_sum':'Weekly_in_degree',
     'month_count':'monthdays',
     'value_mean':'Weekly_in_averge_amount'}

df1 = df1.rename(columns=d).reset_index()
```

---

```
print (df1)
  user       date  Weekly_in_averge_amount  Weekly_in_max_amount  \
0    a 2017-04-03                      1.0                     2   
1    b 2017-04-06                      4.0                     5   
2    c 2017-04-09                      7.5                     9   

   Weekly_in_min_amount  Weekly_in_totalamount  Weekly_in_degree  monthdays  
0                     0                      3                12          3  
1                     3                     12                21          3  
2                     6                     30                42          4
```

Comment: Thanks for your help
But I run the above code and it did not work as expected. However, let's take the following example, 
`user   date                 Weekly_in_averge_amount   count
    29   2011-05-25                 1.512015  ...         34
the 29 user has a grouped 34 transactions. How can I get all transactions of that user